# $http post return 400 on google chrome angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, http, post

well I have this issue when I use $http.post of angularjs on google chrome it always returned with **error 400** which is **bad request**, however when I tried on Mozilla Firefox it works fine!

this is the $http services code

```
$http({
       'method': "POST",
       'url': "http://example.com",
       'data': data,
       'withCredentials': true,
       'cache': false,
       headers: {
                 'Content-type': 'application/json',
                 'authTokens': sessionServices.get('userLogin').userLoginTokens,
                 'JSESSIONID': sessionServices.get('JSESSIONID')
                 }
       }).
       success(function(data, response, headers, status) {
                              console.log("sucess");     
                                }).
       error(function(data, response) {
                              console.log("failed");
                                });
```

this is the example data intput on the $http request it self

```
data = [123415, 32324123, 1123124123, 1213123]
```

**NOTE***

- the url that I submitted to which is the backend is in another domain so for example I deployed the application on http://example1.com while the backend is on http://example.com, at first I thought it was CORS issue but then apparently I passed the OPTION call and when moved to the second call which is the POST request it self then it returned with the error 400
- apparently the chrome ignores my custom headers option set which is 'application/json', but in chrome it returned differently. you could see the returned call below

Remote Address:example1.com
    Request URL:example.com
    Request Method:POST
    Status Code:400 Bad Request

```
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,id;q=0.6,ms;q=0.4
authTokens:13f4ca0d-eb30-435b-b313-a78ed8fff5ef
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:313
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8 application/json
Cookie:JSESSIONID=F524FAFC1178EE3451A7D82CBAD9BE87
Host:http://example1.com
JSESSIONID:F524FAFC1178EE3451A7D82CBAD9BE87
Origin:http://example.com
Referer:http://example.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Request Payload
view source
[d6fece6d-fd4b-4377-b326-7e7cdafbe02b, 6240a840-29a7-4e16-899a-2db0fde6ffdd,…]
0: "d6fece6d-fd4b-4377-b326-7e7cdafbe02b"
1: "6240a840-29a7-4e16-899a-2db0fde6ffdd"
2: "794ae064-38f3-4324-8cda-5afaabe2347d"
3: "41d28490-624d-418d-8fda-4a0ed8c65aa2"
4: "38e06d09-1d33-42d2-b6a2-e06548743a1a"
5: "7f8e92c8-4217-443a-9830-3da78a75b1a6"
6: "ed31b19a-2b2a-4fd7-99b8-b5b61d6a881f"
7: "2b1b8636-d342-4114-9de3-40d42003790f"

Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:example1.com
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Jsessionid
Connection:close
Content-Language:en
Content-Length:990
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 15 Oct 2014 15:25:48 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Vary:Origin
```

do you have this issue as well ?? could you guys help me ??

Comment: Try setting content type to `'text/plain'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's because of the incorrect `Content-Type` header:

```
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8 application/json
```

In your JavaScript code there's a typo:

```
       headers: {
             'Content-type': 'application/json',
```

It has to be `-Type`, capital T. The default is `application/json` anyway so you can as well remove that line.

It could be that Chrome merges `Content-type` and `Content-type` whereas Firefox sends either two separate headers or only one of them.

Comment: you sir is MY HERO!! yes typo it is.. thank you so much, how could I missed this, silly me =.= @zeroflagL